# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="<cmd> <arg>" gives Error : Could not find or load main class <arg>

Tags: bash, shell, jvm, quotes

I have set JAVA_OPTS as

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:gc.log  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Xms100m -Xmx100m -XX:MaxPermSize=5M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=100m -Xss100k -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:CompileThreshold=100  -XX:HeapDumpPath=/usr/share/$package -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:OnError=$TEMP_CMD -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=$TEMP_CMD"
```

then am running the command "trinidad -p "

In $TEMP_CMD, if I use command without any argument then OutOfMemoryError occurs and the $TMP_CMD command also runs. But if I use any argument with a command then the following output is shown

```
Error: Could not find or load main class <arg>
```

arg is the argument

Can anyone give me the solution?

Are there any changes to be made in trinidad.yml or any other cofig file?

Comment: what command ? add the $TEMP_CMD that does not work please

Comment: I tried $TEMP_CMD="echo success" and $TEMP_CMD="\"echo success\""

Answer (score 7):

Try

`export JAVA_OPTS="... \"-XX:OnError=$TEMP_CMD\" ..."`

or

`export JAVA_OPTS='... "-XX:OnError=$TEMP_CMD" ...'`

See [Bash nested quotes and eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510362/bash-nested-quotes-and-eval) and http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html.

**Update**

The above appears still not to work after testing.

test.sh

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx32m '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=echo %p'"
java $JAVA_OPTS Test
```

gives

```
$ bash -x ./test.sh
+ JAVA_OPTS=' -Xmx32m '\''-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=echo %p'\'''
+ java -Xmx32m ''\''-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=echo' '%p'\''' Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=echo
```

fail.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx32m -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"echo %p\""
java $JAVA_OPTS Test
```

gives

```
$ bash -x ./test.sh
+ JAVA_OPTS=' -Xmx32m -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo %p"'
+ java -Xmx32m '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo' '%p"' Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: %p"
```

fail.

Diagnostics with `-x` bash option helped to google that the root of the problem is in a strange mix of bash variable substitution and word splitting rules: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.

There are several possible workarounds.

1) Use helper script to get rid of obstinate spaces

```
JAVA_OPTS+=" -Xmx32m -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/usr/tmp/test/oom.sh"
java $JAVA_OPTS Test
```

2) Move `OnOutOfMemoryError` out of variable

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx32m"
java $JAVA_OPTS -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo %p" Test
```

gives

```
$ bash -x ./test.sh
+ JAVA_OPTS=' -Xmx32m'
+ /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/java -Xmx32m '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=echo %p' Test
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "echo 1639"...
1639
```

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't escape the space. Is there any way to escape the space between the command and the argument? I have tried '\'